# Creating a slider with appendTo and using hide/show visibility classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an image slider, what I'm trying to do is to re-arrange the HTML elements using: first and appendTo and then apply a CSS class of "display visible" to this: first image and apply another CSS class of "display: hidden" to the other two images. So it's showing the: first image and hiding the other two while going through the three images.

So my question is: How do I target the: first image to be visible and hide the other two images, while re-ordering through the images using appendTo

HTML

```
<div class="row kcslider">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="kcslider__imgs">
                        <img class="showSlider" src="img/unauth/slider-one.jpg">
                        <img class="hideSlider" src="img/unauth/slider-two.jpg">
                        <img class="hideSlider" src="img/unauth/slider-three.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.showSlider{
    visibility: visible;
}

.hideSlider{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

jQuery

```
var slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
    slideTimer;


    function nextSlide() {
        var currentSlide = $(".kcslider__imgs img:first");
        $(".kcslider__imgs img:first").appendTo(".kcslider__imgs");


        if (currentSlide.hasClass("showSlider")) {
            currentSlide.removeClass("showSlider");
            currentSlide.addClass("hideSlider");
        }
        if (currentSlide.hasClass("hideSlider")) {
            currentSlide.removeClass("hideSlider");
            currentSlide.addClass("showSlider");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What issue are you having? I don't see a question in your post.

Comment: @DarthJDG How do I target the :first image to be visible and hide the other two images, while re-ordering through the images using appendTo, so with appendTo the second image will become the :first and will be shown while the other two are hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep rotating your images with `appendTo()`, you can simply do the visibility purely via CSS by using the `:first-child` selector.

I would also use `display` instead of `visibility` in the CSS, as visibility keeps the hidden elements in the document flow.

```js
var slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);

function nextSlide() {
    $(".kcslider__imgs img:first").appendTo(".kcslider__imgs");
}
```

```css
.kcslider__imgs img {
    display: none;
}

.kcslider__imgs img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="kcslider">
    <div class="kcslider__imgs">
        <img class="showSlider" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300?text=1">
        <img class="hideSlider" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300?text=2">
        <img class="hideSlider" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300?text=3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what a simple but effective solution...Thought I'd have to tamper with JS but this does the trick, thanks